# Why is the sprite image not resetting to default when I'm not pressing anything in this pygame script?

Tags: pygame

```
import pygame
from config import *
from spritesheet import *
import math

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):

        self.game = game
        self._layer = PLAYER_LAYER
        self.groups = self.game.all_sprites
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

        self.x = x * TILESIZE2
        self.y = y * TILESIZE2
        self.width = PLAYERSIZEX
        self.height = PLAYERSIZEY

        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0

        self.facing = 'right'
        self.animation_loop = 0
    
        self.allowed_to_animate = 1


        self.image = self.game.mario.get_sprite(0, 8, self.width, self.height)

        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (TILESIZE2, TILESIZE2))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y
    
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.jump = False
        self.inAir = False


    def update(self):
        self.movement()
        self.animate()

        self.rect.x += self.x_change
        self.collide_blocks('x')
        self.rect.y += self.vel_y
        self.collide_blocks('y')
    
        if self.facing == "right":
            self.game.mario.get_sprite(0, 8, self.width, self.height)

        self.x_change = 0
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (TILESIZE2, TILESIZE2))

    def movement(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                sprite.rect.x += PLAYER_SPEED
            self.x_change -= PLAYER_SPEED
            self.facing = "left"
  
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                sprite.rect.x -= PLAYER_SPEED
            self.x_change += PLAYER_SPEED
            self.facing = "right"
            
        if keys[pygame.K_z] and self.jump == False and self.inAir == False:
            self.vel_y = -15
            self.jump = True
            self.inAir = True
        
        if keys[pygame.K_z] == False:
            self.jump = False
        
        self.vel_y += 1
        
        if self.vel_y > 10:
            self.vel_y = 10
 

    def collide_blocks(self, direction):
        if direction == "x":
            hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.blocks, False)
            if hits:
                if self.x_change > 0:
                    self.rect.x = hits[0].rect.left - self.rect.width
                    for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                        sprite.rect.x += PLAYER_SPEED
                if self.x_change < 0:
                    self.rect.x = hits[0].rect.right
                    for sprite in self.game.all_sprites:
                        sprite.rect.x -= PLAYER_SPEED

            if direction == "y":
            hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.blocks, False)
            if hits:
                if self.vel_y > 0:
                    self.rect.y = hits[0].rect.top - self.rect.height
                    self.inAir = False
              
                if self.vel_y < 0:
                    self.rect.y = hits[0].rect.bottom                     
                    self.inAir = False

    def animate(self):
        run_anim_right = [self.game.mario.get_sprite(20, 8, self.width, self.height),
                    self.game.mario.get_sprite(38, 8, self.width, self.height),
                    self.game.mario.get_sprite(56, 8, self.width, self.height),]

        run_anim_left = [self.game.mario.get_sprite(76, 25, self.width, self.height),
                    self.game.mario.get_sprite(58, 25, self.width, self.height),
                    self.game.mario.get_sprite(40, 25, self.width, self.height),]
                
        jump_right = self.game.mario.get_sprite(96, 8, self.width, self.height)
        jump_left = self.game.mario.get_sprite(0, 25, self.width, self.height)

        if self.facing == "right":
            if self.inAir == False:
                if self.x_change == 0:
                    self.animation_loop = 0
                    self.game.mario.get_sprite(0, 8, self.width, self.height)
                    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (TILESIZE2, TILESIZE2))

                else:
                    self.image = run_anim_right[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
                    self.animation_loop += 0.1
                    if self.animation_loop >= 3:
                        self.animation_loop = 0
                    
            else:
                self.image = jump_right

        if self.facing == "left":
            if self.inAir == False:
                if self.x_change == 0:
                    self.animation_loop = 0
                    self.game.mario.get_sprite(96, 25, self.width, self.height)
                    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (TILESIZE2, TILESIZE2))

                else:
                    self.image = run_anim_left[math.floor(self.animation_loop)]
                    self.animation_loop += 0.1
                    if self.animation_loop >= 3:
                        self.animation_loop = 0
                
            else:
                self.image = jump_left
```

I've tried and tried again to set the image to default `(self.game.mario.get_sprite(0, 8, self.width, self.height)` but nothing I seem to do works. I've tried adding everything, from trying to make the x speed to 0 (didnt work), and like, everything. Since you guys can somehow figure this stuff out, and I really need help

(full program here: https://replit.com/@PikadaveStudios/Mario-Creepypasta-Game?v=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default image doesn't magically come back. You need to keep the default image and set the default image at the beginning of `animate`:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        # [...]

        self.default_image = self.game.mario.get_sprite(0, 8, self.width, self.height)
        self.image = self.default_image.copy()

        # [...]

    def animate(self):
        self.image = self.default_image.copy()

        # [...]
```

Comment: Alright, I will try that, thank you!